# How to set gridview row colors, I Tried,but it shows cast is not valid?

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void gvcolors_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int esal = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_Sal");
        if (esal > 12000)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Specified cast is not valid.I am taking Emp_Sal , int datatype..but it shows an exception..is it correct or not.please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

> int esal = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Emp_Sal");

You might want to try

```
int esal = (int)e.Row.Cells[1].Text; //index of the Emp_Sal column
```

You should use int.tryparse.