# How to set row color in gridview based on Emp_sal column values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int esal = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString());
        if (esal > 12000)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
        else if (esal == 15000)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }

    }
```

I tried this,but i got an exception like input string was not in correct format..please help me...

Comment: what is the value of e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString()?

Comment: i use int datatype for Emp_sal column in database

Comment: is it getting correct value of the cell??

Comment: no..It will always shows an exception

Comment: if its null then try this int.Parse(Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[3].Text); if this doesnt work i guess you are giving the wrong index of cell.

Comment: If you were to just look at the value of e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString() without trying to parse it to an int what is the value?

Comment: Man you should have included null check and used int.TryParse as I suggested in my previous post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001783/how-to-set-gridview-row-colors-i-tried-but-it-shows-cast-is-not-valid/19002124#19002124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[3].Text))
{

    int esal = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString());
    if (esal > 12000)
    {
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
        e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
    }
    else if (esal == 15000)
    {
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
        e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
        e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i use int data type for this

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int esal = -1;
    if(int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString(),out esal))
    {
        if (esal > 12000)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
        else if (esal == 15000)
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Brown;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
            e.Row.Font.Italic = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         //show message the that e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString() doesn't contain integer.
    }
}
```